# data to and fro hang Xively

Tags: python, xively

I have a python script running on a raring BBBLack ubuntu image that has wiFi working flawlessly, but while using the python script as follows I'm see that the script runs but the Request Log on the xively dashboard isn't receiving anything?!

Is there a frequency limit for which I can update the feeds?

Or is it my App? Which I think is running and not going down.

here's the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import xively
import subprocess
import time
import datetime
import requests
import serial
import re
import string
from select import select

#OS variables and other settings for UART transfer
os.system("sudo chmod 777 -R  /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots")

os.system("sudo echo ttyO1_armhf.com > /sys/devices/bone_capemgr.8/slots")

serial = serial.Serial("/dev/ttyO1", baudrate=9600)

resp = ""
inData = ['']*14
started = False
ended = False
check_point = 0
check_point_listener = 0

# extract feed_id and api_key from environment variables
FEED_ID = "34534"
API_KEY = "blahhblahh"
DEBUG =   "DEBUG" or false
DEBUG_listener = "DEBUG" or false

# initialize api client
api = xively.XivelyAPIClient(API_KEY)

# function to return a datastream object. This either creates a new datastream,
# or returns an existing one
def get_datastream(feed):
  try:
    datastream = feed.datastreams.get("Lock_Controller")
    if DEBUG:
      print "Found existing datastream"
    return datastream
  except:
    if DEBUG:
      print "Creating new datastream"
    datastream = feed.datastreams.create("Lock_Controller", tags="ON/OFF")
    return datastream

# function to return a datastream object. This either creates a new datastream,
# or returns an existing one
def get_datastream_listener(feed):
  try:
    datastream_listener = feed.datastreams.get("load_avg")
    if DEBUG:
      print "Found existing datastream"
    return datastream_listener
  except:
    if DEBUG:
      print "Creating new datastream"
    datastream_listener = feed.datastreams.create("load_avg", tags="load_01")
    return datastream_listener


# main program entry point - runs continuously updating our datastream with the
def run():
  print "Script initiation"

  #Initializing one channel
  feed = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)
  datastream = get_datastream(feed)
  datastream.max_value = None
  datastream.min_value = None
  #Initializing one channel
  feed_listener = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)
  datastream_listener = get_datastream_listener(feed_listener)
  datastream_listener.max_value = None
  datastream_listener.min_value = None

  while True:
     while serial.inWaiting() > 0:
           inChar = serial.read() # Read a character
           if inChar =='<': # not sure what to put in if statement to run until end 
              global started
              started = True
              global ended
              ended = False
              index = 0
           elif inChar =='>':
              global ended
              ended = True            
           if started == True:
              inData[index] = inChar # Store it
              index = index + 1      # Increment where to write next
              #inData[index] = '\0'   # Null terminate the string     
           if ended == True: 
              global ended
              ended = False
              index = 0
              Data = inData #values of acclerometer like "545X" etc enter and stored in Data 
              print (Data) 
              values = "".join(str(v) for v in Data)    
              print (values)       
              strData = string.replace(values, "<", "")
              strData = string.replace(strData, ">", "")
              strData = string.replace(strData, " ", "")
              strData = string.replace(strData, "\0", "")
              print (strData)
              if strData[0] == 's' and strData[1] == 't':
                 print "Nishant Here"
                 strData = string.replace(strData, "st", "")
                 strData = string.replace(strData, "\0", "")
                 strData = string.replace(strData, " ", "")
                 print strData
                 if strData == '1':
                    print "This is arrived at 1"   
                    global check_point_listener              
                    datastream_listener.current_value = str(check_point_listener) + "h"
                    datastream_listener.update()
                    #serial.write("<v0" + str(check_point) + ">") #serial write value 
                    time.sleep(1)
                    datastream_listener.current_value = 0
                    datastream_listener.update()
                 elif strData == '0':
                    print "This is arrived at 0"   
                    global check_point_listener                
                    datastream_listener.current_value = str(check_point_listener) + "L"
                    datastream_listener.update()                  
                    time.sleep(1)
                    datastream_listener.current_value = 0
                    datastream_listener.update()
     if DEBUG:
               print "Updating Xively feed with value: %s"   
               global check_point
               check_point = 0 
               datastream = get_datastream(feed)
               global check_point
               check_point = datastream.current_value
               print "AAGYa: %s" % check_point
               for x in range(1,61):
                   #print x
                   checking = int(check_point)
                   if x == checking:
                       print "Got it"
                       serial.write("<ch" + str(x) + ">")
                       datastream.current_value = 0
                       datastream.update()
     if DEBUG_listener:
               print "Query stuff: %s"   
               global check_point_listener
               check_point_listener = 0 
               datastream_listener = get_datastream_listener(feed_listener)
               global check_point_listener
               check_point_listener = datastream_listener.current_value
               print "AAGYa: %s" % check_point_listener
               check_point_listener = string.replace(check_point_listener, "L", "")
               check_point_listener = string.replace(check_point_listener, "h", "")
               for x in range(1,61):
                   #print x
                   checking = int(check_point_listener)
                   if x == checking:
                       print "Got it Query"
                       serial.write("<Q" + str(x) + ">")             

run()
```

Comment: actually it works all well for some hours like 1 or 2 then with no activity it all hangs

Comment: I have altered the xorg.conf under /etc/X11/ so to add(under Server): Option "BlankTime" "0"
      Option "StandbyTime" "0"
      Option "SuspendTime" "0"
      Option "OffTime" "0"       fearing the reason its hanging is because of it going to sleep!

Comment: anyone          here?????

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my Raspberry pi.

Matters improved when I recreated the feeds and did not rely on them existing all the time.

In your code this means that you have to move:

```
feed = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)
datastream = get_datastream(feed)
datastream.max_value = None
datastream.min_value = None
#Initializing one channel
feed_listener = api.feeds.get(FEED_ID)
datastream_listener = get_datastream_listener(feed_listener)
datastream_listener.max_value = None
datastream_listener.min_value = None
```

into the `while True:` loop.

Hope this helps for you too...